# Battery discharges while AC is plugged in

Tags: 14.10, laptop, power-management, battery, acer

I have a problem with my VN7-571G-56N0.
My battery is discharging while the AC is plugged in.
If i plug in the power cord, after i used the notebook with battery only, it charges it, but when i reached the 100% it doesnt switch to AC only mode. It seems that the battery is used all time and the AC charges it all time.
It doesn't seem to be very healthy for the battery...

Output upower -d:

```
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ADP1
  native-path:          ADP1
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Mi 25 Feb 2015 22:13:46 CET (6206 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    online:             yes

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               LGC
  model:                AC14A8L
  serial:               14728
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Mi 25 Feb 2015 23:56:51 CET (21 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    energy:              53,2722 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         53,2722 Wh
    energy-full-design:  52,497 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    voltage:             12,789 V
    percentage:          100%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.9.23
  can-suspend:     yes
  can-hibernate:   no
  on-battery:      no
  on-low-battery:  no
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  is-docked:       no
```

Output acpi -V:

```
Battery 0: Discharging, 100%, discharging at zero rate - will never fully discharge.
Battery 0: design capacity 4605 mAh, last full capacity 4753 mAh = 100%
Adapter 0: on-line
Thermal 0: ok, 40.0 degrees C
Thermal 0: trip point 0 switches to mode critical at temperature 126.0 degrees C
Thermal 1: ok, 43.0 degrees C
Thermal 1: trip point 0 switches to mode critical at temperature 104.0 degrees C
Cooling 0: x86_pkg_temp no state information available
Cooling 1: intel_powerclamp no state information available
Cooling 2: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 3: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 4: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 5: Processor 0 of 10
```

I'm running a fully updated Ubuntu 14.10.

I appreciate any help to fix this.

Comment: You've already solved this problem, but I still think it would be good if I mentioned that this is probably not related to Ubuntu.

Comment: Due to everything works fine in Windows 8.1 - it is related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

The Battery had to be recalibrated which is easily done by discharging it nearly to zero and charge it again.